# .Net Core Class Library - Copying files to publish (nupkg)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll

I'm creating a .net core class library in which it has an appsettings.json (contains keys which doesn't depend with the consumer like db connection). How will I be able to copy it in the lib\netcoreapp\ upon publish?

[FileNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTNmD.png)

Also this is my code for retrieving the appsettings' values.

```
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location);
        builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "appsettings.json"));

        var config = builder.Build();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First in your csproj file you need to ensure the file "appsettings.json" is copied  to output directory, which could be also so by default (You may able to check the properties of the file in your GUI as well).:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewset</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Second you need to setup the nuspec-file, in this you need to add it:

```
<files>
    <file src="appsettings.json" target="Content\appsettings.json" />
</files>
```

More about this can be found here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/reference/nuspec
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files

If you want to use it within the project where the package is used, you might need to include (link) it as a reference and need to rename it to prevent conflicts in the project. First, in your nuspec you need those file entries as well:

```
<files>
    <file src="appsettings.json" target="Build\appsettings.json" />
    <file src="OriginalName.target" target="Build\NameOfThePackage.targets" />            
 </files>
```

The target file you have to add contains something like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\appsettings.json">
        <Link>MyProjectSetup.json</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

After that, you should see a link to "MyProjectSetup.json", which you can use by update to some dynamic approach, where you change the const string to something dynamic here:

```
builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "appsettings.json"));
```